# Javascript AJAX Upload File

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have written a script in JavaScript to handle a file drag and drop.  When the 'drop' listen is called the file is captured using dataTransfer.files (function below).

```
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    uploadFiles = event.dataTransfer.files; 
    fileBoxUpLoad(uploadFiles);
```

Console log shows the file appears to be capture correctly

```
File {name: "Changi - 2016.pdf", lastModified: 1473382409845, lastModifiedDate: Fri Sep 09 2016 10:53:29 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 197754, …}
```

The fileBoxUpLoad function is call and when the code gets to the xmlhttp.send it throws an error

> Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()

```
var formData = new FormData();
    for(var x=0; x<=item.length; x++) 
    {
        formData.append('file', item[x]);
    }

    var xmlhttps = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttps.open("POST", uri);
    xmlhttps.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
    xmlhttps.send(formData);
```

I understand this means I am trying to parse an Javascript object, when I don't think I am and I can't see where my code is any different to all the tutorials I have read.  Any advice? Thanks!!

Comment: `JSON.parse` doesn't appear anywhere in the code you've shared.

Comment: @Quentin - No it doesn't, that is why I am so confused and struggling to debug it.  :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
//declare an array for store the files
var uploadedFiles = [];

//then get files by using their id or maybe you can loop through on your control
var file = $('input[name=YourControlName]').get(0).files[0];

//push the files to array
uploadedFiles.push(file);

//declare form data and append files to form data
var formData = new FormData();   
for (var i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
    formData.append("file" + i, uploadedFiles[i]);
}

//then you can post to via ajax and get on api via request files
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "",
contentType: false,
data: formData,
processData: false,
success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
},
failure: function (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

});

Comment: Stop's the JSON.parse error but don't submit.  I also think the problem is with the formData file.  Console.log outputs: file, [object FileList]  but when I inspect the variable I can see type error: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)
    at fileBoxUpLoad (http://127.0.0.1/HomeLoans/js/forms.js:309:17)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1/HomeLoans/js/forms.js:286:3)